# possible to move zeros to the end of the array using only std::sort()?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I am working on this question:

> Given an array nums, write a function to move all 0's to the end of it while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements.

I know how to answer this question by just doing in-place swapping, but I also would want to see if it is possible to solve it with `std::sort`.

According to cplusplus.com:

> the comparator function for the sort function is a Binary function that accepts two elements in the range as arguments, and returns a value convertible to bool. The value returned indicates whether the element passed as first argument is considered to go before the second in the specific strict weak ordering it defines.
>
> The function shall not modify any of its arguments.
>
> This can either be a function pointer or a function object.

```
//comments below are based on my understanding
static bool comp(int a, int b){
    //lambda function evaluates to true - no swap, 
    //evaluates to false -swap
    if(a==0) return false;
    if(b==0) return true;
    //if neither a nor b is 0 them do not swap
    return true;
}

void moveZeroes(vector<int>& nums) {
    sort(nums.begin(),nums.end(),comp);
}
```

the given test case is `[0,1,0,3,12]`

my output is `[12,3,1,0,0]`

Comment: This is going to come down to interpretation of the standard.  The `comp` function is stated to need to enforce strict weak ordering.  It's clear that `comp(4, 5)` will be `true`, but `comp(5, 4)` will _also_ be true.  This technically breaks strict weak ordering, however given this use case, I don't think the behavior is _quite_ undefined.

Comment: @Chad It is a strict weak order.  The values `4` and `5` are _equivalent_ for the purposes of this desired sort, so when compared in either order should return false.

Comment: While not directly asked in this question, the intended algorithm for a task like this would be [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) or [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition).

Answer (score 7):

You almost had it right. In your comparator function, you have to return `false` to not swap them. Also, change `std::sort` to [`std::stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort) to keep the values in original order.

```
static bool comp(int a, int b)
{
    //lambda function evaluates to true - no swap, 
    //evaluates to false -swap
    if(a==0) return false;
    if(b==0) return true;
    //if neither a nor b is 0 them do not swap
    return false;
}

void moveZeros(std::vector<int>& nums)
{
    std::stable_sort(nums.begin(),nums.end(),comp);
}
```

## [LIVE DEMO](https://ideone.com/MEk2Fd)

Comment: Or more succinctly, just `return (a!=0) && (b==0);`

Comment: Or just `return b==0;`;

Answer (score 1):

As Drew Dormann pointed out stable partition is the proper algorithm. Here is the code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> data { 0, 1, 0, 3, 12 };

    std::stable_partition(
        data.begin(), data.end(), [](int n) { return n != 0; });

    for (auto i : data)
        cout << i << ' ';

    cout << endl;
}
```

The output is `1 3 12 0 0`

Answer (score 0):

The sort order you want to use is simply that zeros are "greater" than all non-zero values, and equal to other zeros.  All other non-zero values are "less" than zero, and are equivalent to any other non-zero value.

Construct the comparison function properly, then you can use it in a call to `std::stable_sort` to achieve what you're trying to do.